# Groovy runs map and orElseGet on Java Optional at the same time

Tags: java, groovy, lambda, option-type

I encountered strange behaviour with Groovy `2.4.16` and Java `8.0.212-zulu` and `java.util.Optional`.

So, here's the code:

```
def optRegion = new HttpRegion(context).region()

optRegion.map{ region ->
    log.info("FOUND REGION: ${region} - ${optRegion}")
}.orElseGet{
    log.info("NO-REGION, JUST KIDDING! - ${optRegion}")
}
```

And these are the logs:

```
2019-08-27 10:05:31.060 +0200 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-2] INFO  c.n.p.XXX:85 - FOUND REGION: POLAND - Optional[POLAND]
2019-08-27 10:05:31.061 +0200 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-2] INFO  c.n.p.XXX:87 - NO-REGION, JUST KIDDING! - Optional[POLAND]
```

I am using plain Groovy class, without `@CompileStatic` or any other annotations.

The `HttpRegion` returns regular `java.util.Optional`.

```
class HttpRegion {
  HttpRegion(RoutingContext context) {
      this.context = context
  }

  Optional<Region> region() {
      return java.util.Optional.of(...)
  }
}
```

Can anyone explain to me what is wrong, and why both branches of Optional mapping are executed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling `map` on `Optional` *substitutes* content of optional with a value, returned by `map`.

A groovy closure always returns a value.

In this case, it is `null` value, that is why `Optional` becomes empty after a call to `map`

Comment: How is that related to the question? The question was why both branches Optional mapping are executed and not about the returned value. From what I know in Java the `orElseGet()` is meant not to execute if the Optional is not empty.

Comment: Wow, this is awesome. Thanks!

Comment: Nevermind my prev comment. After reading your answer for the 4th time I finally understood what you've meant.

Answer (score 3):

```
optRegion.map{ region ->
    log.info("FOUND REGION: ${region} - ${optRegion}")
}.orElseGet{
    log.info("NO-REGION, JUST KIDDING! - ${optRegion}")
}
```

If you split it into two you'll see that this returns `null` :

```
map{ region ->
    log.info("FOUND REGION: ${region} - ${optRegion}")
}
```

then this closure is called since you had null.

```
orElseGet{
    log.info("NO-REGION, JUST KIDDING! - ${optRegion}")
}
```

If you change your `map` into this:

```
map{ region ->
    log.info("FOUND REGION: ${region} - ${optRegion}")
    return region
}
```

then you should have a single log statement.